# Creating PDF from HTML Forms? Back-End or Front-End Should be Responsible for that?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a Financial Reporting System which developed by angular 8, Customers asked me to put buttons for creating PDF and MSWord Format at the bottom of report pages. Should I handle it at my back-end side or my front-end side? 
I mean should I create the PDF at server and send it to client? or create at client-side?
which library or solution do you suggest?
Thanks...

Comment: What browsers and devices do your users use? If you need to support say IE11, then I would strongly recommend doing HTML to PDF server side. I am not aware of any decent, general usage, client side HTML to PDF converters.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer would be how much clear and responsive pdf you want. If you want to generate a pdf with different templates then you need to go with front-end.
If your template is the same, only the data inside it will be change then you should go with back-end. 
In my experience, If you use jsPDF to convert HTML to pdf, you have to compromise with resolution. If your template is static will never gonna be change then use jsPDF graphics terminology. It will make your page responsive and resolution is far better than others.